# React-native WebView WebKitErrorDomain Error Code: 204

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use WebView to display a video hosted on reddit. The link i am using is https://v.redd.it/e3u0b3ej71k11/DASH_2_4_M which is for this post https://v.redd.it/e3u0b3ej71k11/ . On IOS the video will automatically go full screen and play but gives me this error

[image]

On android it doesn't give me an error but it has a video that is just black, but does have the correct run time. I'm not really sure how the endpoint DASH_2_4_M works but I got that url from reddit api.

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: this.state.data[0].data.children[0].data.media.reddit_video.fallback_url}}
    style={{height: 650, width: '100%'}}
    bounces={false}
    scrollEnable={false}
  />
```

Comment: did you find a solution? i have the same issue for both platforms